# Custom npm library returns an unexpected token where the JSX is returned in a create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app

So I'm attempting my first npm package. It's at its very beginning stages, but I wanted to test it out before I got much further into it. It's basically the beginning stages of core components I'd like to use in my projects. The thing I can't seem to get past is I'm getting an error like this when I return the JSX on my components when I try to include the package...

```
node_modules/core-react-components/src/Switch.js: Unexpected token (60:12)

  58 | 
  59 |         return (
> 60 |             <div className={classnames('switch', className)}>
```

Here's the repo...
https://github.com/bruqui/core-react-components

Here's the npm library...
https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app

I've spent a good bit of time trying to scour the internet for this and can't seem to find the right answer.

In the library itself, it works fine, but as a node_module in another app, this is the error that comes up on all the components where the JSX starts.

Comment: You should build `src` and have `dist/index.js` instead of `src/index.js` as main file. Since you're using CRA, there's already build script, you just need to run it. See how other React libs work.

Comment: OK... Thanks @estus. I didn't realize these packages worked from a build. Like I said, this is my first go at an npm package. I just haven't found any good explanations out there regarding how to do this with React.

Comment: Also, what made me think they didn't use builds is that I don't see the files bundled when I look at other things in the node_modules folder.

Comment: OK... that doesn't seem right unless I go through the webpack config and modify it so it doesn't build this in chunks and what not.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having what seems like the exact problem!